# Using get_posts to get a product closest to todays date, with a date meta - not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Good Morning,

I am currently trying to get  a fooevents product that is closest to todays date, and of a certain product category. I'm using the following code:

```
$lastposts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type'=>'product', 
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'numberposts'      => 1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array('taxonomy' => 'product_cat','field' => 'slug', 'terms' => 'standard-ferry-service' )
    ),
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby'   => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key' => 'WooCommerceEventsDate',
    'meta_type' => 'DATE',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'       => 'WooCommerceEventsDate',
            'compare'   => '>=',
            'value'     => date('F d, Y'),
            'meta_type' => 'DATE',
        )
    )
));
```

However this is seemingly pulling through a random product/event. Can anybody see if i have written anything wrong? The pull through of only the category items is fine, it's just not getting the right one.

Many thanks in advance for any help or advice.

Comment: try to use this data formatting: `date("Y-m-d")` instead of `date('F d, Y')` and let me know if that solve the issue

Comment: @kashalo Thanks so much for the reply, unfortunately not, it still shows the same results. It was formatted the other way simply as the date data from the events is saved in that format. Any other ideas?

Comment: have you replaced the taxonomy with your taxonomy name and the real slug ?

Comment: @AngelDeykov thanks for the reply, I have it written exactly as above. Is there something i am missing? The taxonomy is 'product_cat' and the slug for the category is 'standard-ferry-service'.

Comment: Strange ... try to add ' 'type' => 'NUMERIC' after 'meta_type' => 'DATE', order DESC and as kashalo suggested date("Y-m-d")

Comment: @AngelDeykov thanks again for getting back to me. I've tried that, but that just didn't show any product. When i changed the date format back to the original it ran, but with no difference. Still showing the wrong product. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from the timestamps are stored in the DB as strings, thats why the compare isn't working. With NUMERIC your string should be casted to int and allow comparing

```
$lastposts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type'=>'product', 
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'numberposts'      => 1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array('taxonomy' => 'product_cat','field' => 'slug', 'terms' => 'standard-ferry-service' )
    ),
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby'   => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key' => 'WooCommerceEventsDate',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'       => 'WooCommerceEventsDate',
            'compare'   => '>=',
            'value'     => date('Y-m-d'),
            'type'      => 'NUMERIC' //casting to int
        )
    )
));
```

Comment: Amazing. That has worked. It still needed my original formatting of the date, and ASC, but in regards to the Numeric type instead of date, i think that has worked! Thank you so much for your help!